# By what mechanism does finder insert a space in an app's name?

Tags: macos, finder

I was researching a problem with the Notification Center and noticed that Finder shows the program as **Notification Center**, yet on disk and in the package receipts and installation media, the file is actually NotificationCenter.app *(And the full path to is is /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app)*

[image: Notification Center - with and without a space]

I understand how Finder drops the .app extension by default, but where does the system know to add the space in this app's name?

Comment: Not at my Mac right now so I can't confirm but wouldn't it be listed in the plist inside the bundle?

Comment: @tubedogg I checked there - no spaces at all in any text plist file I have installed on this Mac. What's odd is the code signing also signs the name without a space (both in the .app and the final Contents/MacOS portion, so I'm guessing it's a Finder oddity at this point.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's handled by localization.

If you check the Info.plist, there's a key LSHasLocalizedDisplayName with a value of true.  That means that there are localized names for the application.  Localizations are stored in the app bundle in Contents/Resources.  Since I'm using English, I can look in /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings, and see the name of the app with the space in it.

Strings files are actually binary plists.  You can view them in a human-readable fashion with

```
$ plutil -p /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
{
  "CFBundleDisplayName" => "Notification Center"
  "CFBundleName" => "Notification Center"
}
```

Comment: Since that file is stored in a binary format, might you expand on how you "see" the name there if you didn't just extract random strings from the file as I edited in above? Bonus points for a command line tool that dumps the correct localization directory for a certain locale.

Comment: Hmmmm... Still trying to find a way to find the right directory, since dialect-specific directories make it a bit more complicated.

Comment: That's really a separate question if we don't get a quick "next step - here's the deeper mechanism" behind localization. That it's localized is 90% of the battle here.